# Select Count into Multiple Column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, multiple-columns

I wondering if I can do a unique Select to diferent count of distinct items into many columns. By now this works fine, but doing only one count by column like:

```
SELECT  provincia,count(provincia) as total_provincia
FROM museos
group by provincia ORDER BY provincia
```

[Result of Select for uno count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsIFj.jpg)

Then if a try with other field, still looks good as I needed too:

```
SELECT  localidad,count(localidad) as total_localidad
FROM museos
group by localidad ORDER BY localidad
```

[Result of another Select Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMF11.jpg)

But, when I trying to get both column with its count at one Select query, it's suppose to be something like this:

```
SELECT  provincia,localidad,count(localidad) as total_localidad,
        count(provincia) as total_provincia
FROM museos
group by provincia,localidad ORDER BY provincia,localidad
```

Then I got:

[Select for both count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhUuK.jpg)

i've been looking everywhere around Stack and websites with examples, unfortunately I couldn't find something similar of what I tryied to do, and I realy got no answer for why only seems to work one of the count, and always for the small granular data, in this case, "localidad". At the same time the other count of "provincia" is ignored, and its column named as total is just a copie of the values of the first one, as we can see. So, is it possible to make a Select query that return two or more count made on diferent columns, in order to get this kind of response:

[Hopefull Select query expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRegT.jpg)

I mean, finaly the organization of the required table result in a tree scheme, where data like "provincia" are the body or the root, and its capillary data would be the leaves. It's kind of weird built a Query this way, but I think is not impossible at all. So any help or coment I'll be greatful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `over(partition by)`:

```
select distinct
    provincia, count(provincia) over(partition by provincia) 'count_provincia'
    ,localidad, count(localidad) over(partition by localidad) 'count_localidad'
from museos
order by provincia;
```

Comment: Realy preciated that! a simple chance with over(partition) works perfectly fine! Thanks!